# Custom publish date

Tags: entities, datetime

I need to manipulate the publish date of my nodes on the node entry form. How can I achieve that? Shall I set a date field for my node that will hold the publish date? In case I do that, how can I move the publish date to the node definition? Or do you recommend me to keep this "publish" field apart from the node publish date and have two different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using D6, you use a [hook_node_api($op = 'presave')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6):

```
function custom_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'presave':
      if ($node->type == 'story') {
        //use dsm($node) to explore the variables
        //set the created date to the field value, must be a unix timestamp.
        $node->created = $node->field_published[0]['value'];
      }
  }
}
```

D7, [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7):

```
function custom_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'story') {
    $node->created = $node->field_published[0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Of course using unix timestamp isn't handy so set a [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field and use [date_convert](http://api.lullabot.com/date_convert).

```
$node->created = date_convert($node->field_published[0]['value'], DATE_ISO, DATE_UNIX);
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if I can use that code with the Rules module (for example, picking the before saving option and for the action I would run a custom PHP code)? I am not that much of an advanced Drupal user, so please, allow me a "newbie" question. Does your solution require creating a custom module, or may I place this hook in the template.php? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Marcos I'm not very familiar with rules modules, especially the recent version but if rules give you access to the $node object and run php code I think it's possible. Personally I'd recommend you to create a custom module to store such changes as it's easier to track. This code has to go in a custom.module.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, I will try the first option suggested (taking a look at the translations available for the calendar js.

Answer (score 0):

`date_convert()` apparently doesn't exist under Drupal 7.  I used `strtotime()` to convert my `datetime` field to the Unix time string and enter it into the database:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    $node->created = strtotime($node->field_post_date['und'][0]['value']);
  }
}
```